# array combine not working on variable

Tags: php, arrays

i have tried this script and the result is true

```
$a = array('Allow','Block');
$b = array('yes','no');
$c=array_combine($a,$b);

while (list($key, $value) = each($c)) {
echo "$key: $value \n";
}
```

the true result :

> Allow:yes Block:no

but when i use a varible into the array

```
$val1 = "'Allow','Block'";
$val2 = "'yes','no'";
$a = array($val1);
$b = array($val2);
```

the result is different :

> 'Allow','Block': 'yes','no'

the question is how i can make the first result because i got the text from dynamic varible

Comment: using of variable there, considers a single dimension's value there. you need to utilize different values separating with commas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use arrays like in second example. You should probably try something like this:

```
$val1 = "Allow,Block";
$val2 = "yes,no";
$a = explode(',',$val1);
$b = explode(',', $val2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
$val1 = "Allow,Block";
$val2 = "yes,no";
$a = explode(',',$val1);
$b = explode(',', $val2);
$c=array_combine($a,$b);

while (list($key, $value) = each($c)) {
    echo "$key: $value \n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry dude long time to replay, this forum very helpful. i can't resolved my proble in google search. Because i just stupuid script kiddie... Thanks guys you save my day :D those answer are working!

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the true result by using the simple foreach like:

```
$a = array('Allow','Block'); 
$b = array('yes','no');

$trueResult = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value){
   $trueResult[$value] = $b[$key];
}

foreach($trueResult as $key => $val){
  echo $key . "=". $val."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$val1 = "'Allow','Block'";
$val2 = "'yes','no'";

$val1 = str_replace("'", "", $val1);
$val2 = str_replace("'", "", $val2);
$c = array_combine(explode(',', $val1), explode(',', $val2));

while (list($key, $value) = each($c)) {
    echo "$key: $value \n";
}
```